# Webkit not displaying text with @font-face

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with webkit browsers (Opera and Chrome). I added some fonts to my website and when i open in webkit browsers the texts simply don't appear. But if i resize the window or open the inspector tool, the text appear normally. http://www.roko.com.br/wergo

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Nixie One;
    src: url('nixieone-webfont.eot');
    src: url('nixieone-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('nixieone-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('nixieone-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('nixieone-webfont.svg#nixie_oneregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Index.htm

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:justify;padding:20px;font-family: Nixie One, helvetica">

                        <h1>Gostou a ideia?</h1>
                        <h4>Deixe-nos o seu email e te mandamos notícias! Prometemos não lotar sua caixa de emails!</h4>
                        <form>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="email" style="border:1px solid #ccc;width:100%" />
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div style="width:100%;" align="center">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-large" style="width:60%">Enviar</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide code here in your question - otherwise future readers of the question will not see the original issue(s) that caused you to ask it

Comment: works for me in webkit..

Comment: Opera isn't Webkit based, as far as I know...

Comment: @Kroltan. Opera has been Webkit (Blink) since v15. http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9240534/Opera_15_launches_with_WebKit_backbone

Comment: Oh. Thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. Is some problem with holder.js and webkit. Don't know why, but keep hiding my texts with extra fonts. Removed it, stopped that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try delete all yours @font-face from your CSS and try put to head `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nixie+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

and add this style font for your site `font-family: 'Nixie One', cursive;` and try it.

Comment: That works, but what I do to sources that are not in GoogleApis?

Comment: Actually, only works because the fonts are installed on my pc. If they are not installed, still not working

Comment: Okey try this @font-face {
    font-family: Nixie One;
    src: url('nixieone-webfont.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Comment: Ok then you need to start from beginning and step by step checking when that issue starting